# Is there a way to change the Windows 7 desktop background rotation time?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

Windows 7 allows the background to be rotated automatically at a specified interval as shown below:

[image]

My goal is to set 1 second or less so that pictures I took sequentially appear to be moving.

Is there a way to change the rotation interval to other than to predefined ones?

Comment: It might be better (more CPU/HDD efficient) to convert your sequence of images to a GIF or AVI and play them as movie, directly on your desktop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming it's a registry key but I haven't been able to find it yet. You can use [**Itty Bitty Wallpaper Rotator**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ibwall/) to achieve the same effect though. It allows you to enter any custom time you want and works on XP and Vista as well. Simply tell it which folder contains the wallpapers, set any additional options, and hit **Rotate Now**. Easy as that!

[image]

[image]

Itty Bitty Wallpaper Rotator is free and open source.

Comment: Well if you’re going to resort to third-party tools, there’s [tons of them](http://www.google.com/search?q=wallpaper+changer).

Comment: @Synetech - Well, not all of them let you set the refresh interval down to 1 second precision.

Answer (score 5):

HKCU\Control Panel\Personalization\Desktop Slideshow\Interval, the value is in milliseconds, but from my testing, setting this other than a value in the dropdown will reset it when the drop down is opened.

**Update:** It works as long as you don't reopen the personalization window, then the interval will reset and you'll have to set it in the reg again.

Answer (score 0):

This [background wallpaper switcher](http://www.bionixwallpaper.com/) allows you to refresh the wallpaper at any interval with one-second precision.

[image]

It can also play videos (AVI and GIF) and this is what you may actually want. 
I think it may be more CPU/HDD efficient to convert your sequence of images to a GIF or AVI (DivX codec is supported) and play it like that.