# In Windows 7, where is the setting for how often the desktop is changed stored?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, desktop-customization

On Windows 7, on Personalisation > Desktop Background, selecting multiple wallpapers enables an option called "Change picture every..." with a dropdown for options ranging from "10 seconds" to "1 day". Where in Windows Registry is the currently-selected option in that menu saved? I can't seem to find that particular key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`.

I'm wanting to change my background every 7 days rather than 1, and because - for whatever reason - Windows doesn't allow a custom period of time to switch up wallpapers, I'm hoping there's a place in the registry that saves the answer and can be modified. To preempt any irrelevant answers or comments, I'm aware there are programs that cycle wallpapers from a given folder, but these have their problems for me and are too involved, so if Windows already has the functionality built-in and all that's needed is to find and change a value, I'd much prefer that option.

Comment: See: [Is there a way to change the Windows 7 desktop background rotation time?](http://superuser.com/a/550714)

Comment: Thanks so much, @dxiv! 

Tbh, needing to reset it everytime the Personalisation window is opened is not ideal, so I'm thinking I'll instead go with the option of using the Itty Bitty Wallpaper Rotator linked by another answer in the question you linked; it seems a lot simpler, less involved and more hands off than what I'm currently using, not to mention resource-light. 

If I find it just as problematic as the current one I have, then as a last resort I'll probably just write a .reg file to update the key, just to save the long trip to the registry every time Personalisation is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is located in the Registry at:

```
HKCU\Control Panel\Personalization\Desktop Slideshow\Interval
```

The value is set in milliseconds, which means that in order to cycle the background every 7 days, you'd need to change this value to `604800000`. However, note that opening the Personalisation window via the Desktop or the Control Panel will reset this key to its default value, after which it'll have to be set again.

I personally decided that this solution wasn't ideal for me, so opted for a third-party utility instead. More than a year on, I'm using [John's Background Switcher](https://johnsad.ventures/software/backgroundswitcher/windows/), which I have no real complaints with.