# Where is the preference for the timing on wallpaper slideshows kept?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, remote, desktop-customization

I feel like such a setting should be somewhere in the registry, but can't find anything which is obviously "time between change".

Bonus points if it's easy to change on a remote machine on the network!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I feel like such a setting should be somewhere in the registry

> There is a **registry entry** which contains (but not controls) **the
>   current slideshow duration in miliseconds**. It is
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Personalization\Desktop Slideshow\Interval
> ```
>
> You can change it, but the next time you use the theme, the duration
>   will be 15 minutes again. That **duration is copied from**:
>
> ```
> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\theme_name\theme_name.theme
> ```
>
> (a text file) where there is an item named ***Interval*** near the end
>   of the file. You can **change the value of that entry to**, say:
>
> ```
> Interval=14400000
> ```
>
> which is **4 hours**, or any other value. But **I do not know where
>   the 15 minutes duration comes initially from**.

Source [Windows 7/8 Wallpaper Registry Keys (Slideshow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27243887/3536342), answer by [Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890763/apps)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Is there a way to change the Windows 7 desktop background rotation time?](https://superuser.com/questions/112719/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-windows-7-desktop-background-rotation-time)

Comment: I should certainly learn to read more thoroughly! I'll give that a go ☺

Comment: @BenjiHare It's all a question of google-fu :)

Comment: clearly I have much to learn in this art! (Plus it's easier to outsource while at work ;) )